# Flexbox layout issue in chrome with spaces

Tags: css, html, layout, flexbox

Hey I am currently rocking a flex box layout.

I am having an issue in chrome where a space in the label div seems to be creating some extra space at the bottom of the row for no reason, in internet explorer it is fine and in chrome with no space it is fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.popup-body{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

div.popup-form-container{
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:green;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: center;
}

div.popup-form-control-container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.checkbox-container{
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction:row;
}

div.checkbox-label{
    flex:1;
    font-family:Segoe UI;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.checkbox-control{
    flex:1;
    font-family:Segoe UI;
    background-color:white;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.field{
    flex:none;
    background-color:purple;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup-body">
        <div class="popup-form-container">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="popup-form-control-container">
                    <div class="checkbox-container">
                        <div class="checkbox-label">Hello world</div>
                        <div class="checkbox-control">
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/4246r1f1/

Screen shots:

Chrome error (space)
[image: Chrome space(Error)] 
Chrome ok (no space)
[image: chrome ok (no space)]
IE ok (space)[image]

Comment: you're doing this to make a column of fields?

Comment: just a two column row, label and control using flexbox. There will be more of these rows under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **flexboxes** you need to understand which properties are for the container flexbox and which are related to child/items( [check this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) );

For ex. setting `flex:1` on an item without a container `display:flex` doesn't make sense (found some of these in your code...)

Correcting these the `.field` doesn't overflow (tested on chrome and ff);

### [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/4246r1f1/5/)

Comment: flex:1 with out a display:flex still seems to work fine though.. I managed to figure it out myself yesterday but Ill make this the answer as your solution works.